# WordPress - Load PHP variable so it's not cached (AJAX?)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, caching

I have some PHP code in WordPress (running in the Shortcode Exec PHP plugin) that runs, and loads a variable and displays it in the page.

I have a caching plugin on the site (recently switched to WP-Rocket), and when the plugin is enabled on the whole site, that variable is cached as well, so it doesn't update every time the value changes and the page is reloaded.

How can I load the code/variable with AJAX (or some other method) so that it isn't cached?

Here is the PHP code I'm currently using:

```
include '/full/path/variables.php';

$countsrc = $totalcount;

$count = (int) $countsrc;
switch ($count)
{
    case 0:
        echo "There currently aren't any items in the list.";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "There is currently $count item in the list.";
        break;
    default:
        echo "There are currently $count items in the list.";

}
```

Is there any way to use some method like Ajax to make sure that the variable isn't cached?

Any help/input would be really appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which caching plugin are you using? I'm betting that the AJAX page will be cached too.

Comment: Recently switched to WP-Rocket. I asked them about not caching that part of the page/code, and they recommended writing the script in AJAX so that the value is dynamic.